# Reinitialize a component

Tags: apache-flex

I want to reinitialize a component by clicking a button.I use the following code, but seem nothing is happening.

```
protected function createItem(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.currentState="Viewer";
    this.initialize();
}
```

Why?

Comment: What component, or type of component, are you trying to reinitiliaze?  What does the this.initialize() method do?  How do you define re-initialize?  Are you referring to the Flex Component lifecycle; and want to re-create all of a component's children?  Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Yes I am referring the Flex Component lifecycle. I know there have four step for flex to create a Component, but Is there having a method to force Flex to execute those step again?

Comment: And initialize() is a method to Initializes the internal structure of this component.

Comment: and I only need to re-create a component, so that I can refresh and capture some new data form the database.

Comment: You need to recreate a component to get new data? Doesn't make much sense to me. Just give the existing component new data.

Comment: Yep you are right that sound stupid =.='. The existing component seem stick with the old data. and I dont know how I should program the component get new data. I had thought recall all the service but dont know how to put it back to the component. Thank RIAstar, finally I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes I am referring the Flex Component lifecycle. I know there have
>   four step for flex to create a Component, but Is there having a method
>   to force Flex to execute those step again?

Actually, there are much more steps than four to the Flex Component Lifecycle.  See [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html) and [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) for more information.

What you may mean is that there are four methods run as part of the Flex Component LifeCycle; and those are createChildren(), commitProperties(), updateDisplayList(), and measure().  In the MX architecture, there is also a layoutChrome() method, but that is not commonly used.

In Flex 4 Spark architecture; there are a lot of other hooks (partAdded(), partRemoved()) but they all extend off the MX Architecture.

You may benefit from using the invalidation methods:

- run invalidateProperties() on a component to force the commitProperties() to re execute during the next render event
- run invalidateDisplayList() on a component to force the updateDisplayList() method to re-execute during the next render event
- run invalidateSize() on a component to force the measure() method to re-execute during the next render event
- In a Flex 4, Spark component, run invalidateSkinState() to force getCurrentSkinState() method to re-execute during the next render event.

  You can also remove a component from the stage using removeChild()--removeElement() for Spark containers--and then addChild()--addElement for Spark containers.  That would essentially force the component to re-start it's process.

  You could also create a brand new instance of the component and remove the old one.

Comment: I though my bug may solve by re-initaize the compenent. Yep, Any way thanks for the answer, I know my question is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem. May be it is better if I post here for my method.

I just add two line to recall the service and place it to the variable which the Compenent is using and everything works fine.

```
    protected function createItem(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.currentState="Viewer";
        this.initialize();

countResult.token = productdetailService.count();
countResult2.token = getNewProductIDService.count();

    }
```